# Private variable not working as expected?

Tags: php, oop

Before I get downvoted into oblivion, let me say that I am an experienced Front End Dev trying to learn PHP to make me a better programmer. I need help understanding why the following code still prints out my private variable. I thought that an error would be thrown when trying to access it via an inherited class.

```
<?php
class Kopi
{
 private $name = 'Kopi';

    function __construct()
    {
      $this->getName();      
    }
    function getName()
    {
      echo $this->name;   
    }
}

class Dog extends Kopi
{
       function __construct()
       {
            Parent::getName();   
       }
}

$kopi = new Dog;
```

Comment: `Parent::getName(); ` aren't this means it call the base class (its parent, in this case `Kopi`) so its still valid since **`$name` is accessible from `Kopi`** obviously.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php and then have a look under **"extends"** if you haven't already.

Comment: I just hope you are not about to file a bug report :-) "extends" only duplicates a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your property, `$name`, is private. The method you're using on the other hand is not.

You don't have direct access to `$name` but your getter method will be perfectly able to retrieve the value.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php